# MySql: How to Join by either one of two columns

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to figure out how to join a table with another based on one of two values from either one of two fields.  I have  person table and a personrelationship table.  I want to join the personrelationship table but am not sure how.  What I'm trying to do is get a list of people and determine if the current user has a relationship to anyone on the list.

Person Table

```
 id  |  name
 1      Bob
 2      Jack
```

Person Relationship Table

```
person1_id | person2_id | status
      1           2          1
```

Query (Not sure on this)

```
Select *
FROM person p
LEFT JOIN personrelationship pr ON 
/* if :current_user_id is either person1_id or person2_id */
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it with or condition like:

```
Select *
FROM person p
LEFT JOIN personrelationship pr 
ON p.id = pr.person1_id OR p.id = pr.person2_id
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot you could do a condition on the join like that.